# Android ADT and SDK Installation

Tags: android, sdk, installation

> > > Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Connection timed out: connect

I've encountered above error when I install SDK revision10 and ADT10 on eclipse galileo.
I used older version lately and it worked well.
But now I can't even install SDK.
What do I do?
Please reply me ASAP.
Best Regards,

Comment: must be internet connection/firewall issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http rather than https